# Compare tuple with list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
planta_accesibles = probpl.RelacionRigida(
        lambda a1, p1, p2: (a1,(p1,p2))
                in [('A0', ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4'))]
        )
```

I want to search if p1 and p2 are included in my list 'A0', but python compare tuple "p1,p2" with tuple '0,1'. If I hold on " '2', '3', '4' " I don´t take a correct reponse.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please check [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to improve your chance to get an answer.

Comment: what is the function: `probpl.RelaciónRígida()`? It seems you pass it a lambda function as its argument. Can you give an example input and output for this lambda function?

Comment: Since we're discussing that function already: avoid using high-ASCII characters in your code. While their support is common these days, it is good practice to nonetheless avoid having to rely on these (plus, in many languages, they're not allowed).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `probpl.RelaciónRígida()` is so I can't know what that needs, but I think I can sort of recognize what you're trying to do with the lambda function (feel free to correct me or ask questions).

It looks like you want to have a list named `'A0'` and test if `p1` and `p2` are contained in it. In this case, I believe a dictionary would suit your needs better than a nested tuple:

```
ref = {"A0": ("0", "1", "2", "3", "4")}
```

This allows you to test the dictionary to determine if it contains a value (your tuple) associated with the key `a1`:

```
a1 in ref
```

After determining the dictionary contains an entry for `a1`, you can test whether that entry contains `p1` and `p2`:

```
(p1 in ref[a1]) and (p2 in ref[a1]) #parenthesis are only added for readability
```

If I were to add this to your existing example it would look something like:

```
ref = {"A0": ("0", "1", "2", "3", "4")}
test = lambda a1, p1,p2: (a1 in ref) and (p1 in ref[a1]) and (p2 in ref[a1])
planta_accesibles = probpl.RelaciónRígida(test)
```